# Azure Url restrictions/ Blocking on VM

Tags: azure, security, virtual-machine

How to allow only one url to Azure Vm and restrict all other url? For example i need only stackoverflow.com url to work on my azure vm and restrict other any * urls

Not getting how to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through your network security groups in the Azure portal.

You can create an outbound rule that blanket blocks all outbound traffic. Then create another rule above it that allows traffic to the specific URL you want.